# What is the best way to delete all files in a user profile, without deleting the user profile in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I suppose this has been mentioned before, but the answers are quite inconsistent and might not totally address what I am looking for.

I have a user profile created, and I want to delete all types of files, ie. desktop, all documents and everything else.

What is the best and easiest way to go about this? I have admin access. The user accounts are not admin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if a user is created,It would create folder under the users directory  in the C drive so to delete  the user from another user

Please follow the below steps

(i) Login into the user that has admin access

(ii) Now open the C:/Users/user_name and then you can find the various folder create for that like download/desktop so you can delete the folder which you need.

Comment: I see folders like My Documents, My Music, Desktop... can I just delete the entire folder? There wont be any problems right?

Comment: @vemutech my question above.

Comment: And what if the user saves files in C:/ and not in My Documents.

Comment: Yes there wont be any problem.

You can delete various folder under the location C:/Users/user_name but we can'the delete the entire   user_name folder  since it contain application  data folder  which is an hidden folder and  would store the cache location  and default application information.

Comment: If the other user saves the files in C:/ then current  user cant be able to find that which user create the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete only the user's folder (e.g. C:\Users\moses) without deleting the account, you better use [delprof2](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/).

There are some reg keys that would prevent the user to log on if he has no folder, and delprof2 delete those keys along with the folder.